# Batch renaming files and folders in Python using f.replace() and os.rename() inside os.walk()

Tags: python, str-replace, batch-rename, os.walk, python-os

I have a database with the following structure:

```
dataset1
- subject-1
    - session-1
        - group1
            - subject-1_session-1_other-stuff-01.json
            - subject-1_session-1_other-stuff-01.txt
            - subject-1_session-1_other-stuff-02.json
            - subject-1_session-1_other-stuff-02.txt
        - group2
            - files-i-dont-care-about.bvec
        - group3
            - subject-1_session-1_other-different-stuff-01.json
            - subject-1_session-1_other-different-stuff-01.txt
            - subject-1_session-1_other-different-stuff-02.json
            - subject-1_session-1_other-different-stuff-02.txt
    - session2
        - group1
            - subject-1_session-2_other-stuff-01.json
            - subject-1_session-2_other-stuff-01.txt
            - subject-1_session-2_other-stuff-02.json
            - subject-1_session-2_other-stuff-02.txt
        - group2
            - differently-named-files-i-dont-care-about.bvec
        - group3
            - subject-1_session-2_other-different-stuff-01.bval
            - subject-1_session-2_other-different-stuff-01.bvec
            - subject-1_session-2_other-different-stuff-02.bval
            - subject-1_session-2_other-different-stuff-02.bvac
- subject-2 
       - ^ etc
```

I want to remove the beginning of the files (subject-x_session-x_) and keep the other-stuff*.* and other-different-stuff*.* and so on. I'm using * here as UNIX expansion but not sure if I can use that inside a variable as input. I think one problem is that when the script tries to place the new filenames in the proper directory, the directory does not dynamically direct to the file's origin. Hoping I can still use os.walk(), but it seems that this function retrieves an array all at once and is over before I can call os.rename(). I think I need to be able to call os.rename() piecewise before os.walk() completes. Otherwise I'm having to run the script on each specific directory to change the names, but this is a large database. Here's what I'm starting with:

```
root = /full-path/database/
find = "subject-1" 
# ^ ideally this would find any string starting with subject-{any number}_session-{any number} but I'd be happy just to get the explicit string to work

replace_with = ""

list = os.walk(root)

for root, dirs, files in list:
    for file in files:

            new_filename = file.replace(find, replace_with)
            src = os.path.join(root, file) 
            dst = os.path.join(root, new_filename)
            os.rename(src, dst)
            print(filename + " renamed to " + new_filename)
```

The script fails when os. rename() is called. Is it reasonable to iterate through a directory of varying depth and change these files in one go?

I'm thinking something like a map function or multiple for loops inside a larger one, but I've hit a wall..